# Extract from DMG

Tags: macos, extract, dmg

How to extract content of DMG without mounting it?
I want add autoupdate system to my application. It downloads DMG from website, then extract new version of application from it.

Comment: Your question is directing you into the wrong direction... "autoupdate" is a mechanism inherently supported by MacOS Installer (framework, and service) - and you can rely on this (make your .pkg installer update the existing installed version) rather on manually merging the contents of a volume in a .dmg and your installation on the local drive. I recommend that you consider using official installer package for "autoupdates".

Answer (score 12):

Some `.dmg` files can be extracted by using [7-zip](http://7-zip.org).

```
$ 7z x your.dmg
$ ls
your.dmg
0.MBR
1.Primary GPT Header
2.Primary GPT Table
3.free
4.hfs
5.free
6.Backup GPT Table
7.Backup GPT Header
```

...and after extracted the `4.hfs` file:

```
$ 7z x 4.hfs
```

...you'll get the content of the `.dmg` file.

You could also mount the `.dmg` in Mac OS X using `hdiutil` command (which is also used by [Homebrew Cask](http://caskroom.io)).

Please refer to [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38112/how-can-i-open-a-dmg-file) for more use cases on Linux.

Comment: 7zip is Windows-only

Comment: @BenLeggiero Not really, install p7zip on Linux/macOS which contains the `7z` command-line application.

Comment: Extracting dmg files with 7z seem to miss the executable bits, making extracted applications from DMGs dysfunctional. May be related: https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/113/

Comment: On macOS there are two Homebrew packages that provide 7-Zip: [`p7zip`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip) and [`sevenzip`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sevenzip). `p7zip` is a fork and `sevenzip` the original implementation. It might be of interest, that `p7zip` does not  currently support APFS images, the `sevenzip` formula however does.

Answer (score 4):

Dmg is just a format used for MacOS. It's a not compressed file format like `zip` or `tar.gz`
You have several choices to mount it. Here are some options.

1. Double click on it to mount it.
2. Use `hdiutil attach your.dmg` to mount the dmg file. After mounting on it,
   operating your command line to extract the files you want out.

Comment: This is what I needed. Can one get the mounted path from the terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to extract a .dmg is to use the hdituil and the pkgutil. The .dmg contents has a .pkg files in it. Two options is to go from .dmg directly and extract the files or first mount the .dmg and then extract the .pkg. Here is a link to glorious post that saves me from installing MacOS installer when all hope was lost. Credit to this amazing post won't stole that also it's a result of good searching query lol
https://medium.com/macoclock/extracting-applications-and-other-files-from-pkg-files-on-macos-f885376f1ef3

Answer (score 0):

```py
import subprocess
import re
import shutil

def extract_dmg(download_path, extract_path):
    # Mount the DMG file and capture the output
    output = subprocess.check_output(['hdiutil', 'attach', '-nobrowse', '-readonly', download_path]).decode('utf-8')

    # Extract the mounted volume name from the output
    mounted_volume_name = re.search(r'/Volumes/([^ ]*)', output).group(1)

    # Use the mounted volume name to copy files
    shutil.copytree(f'/Volumes/{mounted_volume_name}/', extract_path)

    # Detach the volume
    subprocess.run(['hdiutil', 'detach', f'/Volumes/{mounted_volume_name}'])

# Usage
download_path = "/path/to/your/download.dmg"
extract_path = "/path/to/extract"

extract_dmg(download_path, extract_path)
```

Answer (score -5):

Doing that is working counter to the design of DMGs, so it's very painful. DMGs are designed to be mounted, that is their whole *raison d'être*. You would need to [rely on experimental code](https://github.com/planetbeing/libdmg-hfsplus) if you wanted to do something like that. You are probably better served by using a non-DMG archive such as a zip file, or by making your automatic updating process download, mount, *and* unmount the DMG file you provide.

Comment: Project which you have linked is a portable solution. Mounting DMG images within OSX is easy as others answers proofed.

Comment: Not only that - but if your .DMG is encrypted, I don't think even "Experimental code" would work for that.